# How can I create a .properties file in folder/jar at runtime in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm using properties files in my program. I want to be able to create/edit `.properties` files in an external folder or internal jar while my program is running.

*For example: if I want to access a file "ex.properties", and it hasn't been created, then I would create it in a folder, otherwise edit it.*

When I use the IDE (Netbean) my program runs fine (creates files/alters files) but whenever I use the distributed jar it doesn't work: `"FileNotFoundException (cannot find the file path specified)"`. If I don't specify a folder (i.e `"ex.properties"` instead of `"folder/ex..."`) it will work but creates the properties in the main folder. I'm rather curious on whether it can be done.

File Structure:

- src
- propFolder (where the properties should go)

I think I could solve the issue by creating properties externally in order to write them at runtime but I can't figure out to do this.

I've tried adding the propFolder to the jar and jar parent folder (to simulate the IDE) after building but it didn't solve the issue.

I believe the issue stems from not being able to access the propFolder (or not being able to alter jar at runtime) but I wanted to know why.

In the meantime I've just kept it without the folder with code in the case of tampering.

Simple Example of my (working) code

```
private Properties config = new Properties();
//configPath = "propFolder/example.properties" won't work here
String configPath = "example.properties";
String key = "exampleKey";
String val = "exampleVal";
config.setProperty(key, val);

try {
    //Error appears here
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(configPath);
    config.store(out, null);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify the resources at runtime.

Comment: What are you intending to save in this properties file?

Comment: It throws an exception because propFolder doesn’t exist. You must create the folder first (with your code naturally).